# SSH, Kerberos, AD: how / where to config /etc/pam.d/password-auth?

Tags: active-directory, ssh, password, kerberos, pam

I have a CentOS 6 machine here and want to give SSH access for users from another forest, which is trusted. I got a temporary workaround, which is:

1) change content in /etc/pam.d/vncserver to

```
auth include password-auth
```

2) add these two lines /etc/pam.d/password-auth

```
auth        sufficient    pam_krb5.so use_first_pass realm=NEW.DOMAIN.NET
password    sufficient    pam_krb5.so use_authtok realm=NEW.DOMAIN.NET
```

so it looks that way:

```
%PAM-1.0
This file is auto-generated.
User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 500 quiet
auth        sufficient    pam_krb5.so use_first_pass
auth        sufficient    pam_krb5.so use_first_pass realm=NEW.DOMAIN.NET
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_unix.so broken_shadow
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 500 quiet
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_krb5.so
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_cracklib.so try_first_pass retry=3 type=
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nis nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_krb5.so use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_krb5.so use_authtok realm=NEW.DOMAIN.NET
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
session     optional      pam_krb5.so
```

3) add new domain name to /etc/krb5.conf

4) restart SSH daemon

--> Works fine, but after each system-config-authentication (authconfig -update_all) the changes from 2) are overwritten (undone) and the SSH-connection is refused then.

My question is where to add the additional new domain to keep it working permanently. A simple substitution won't work, as the old domain / forest is still in use too.

Just adding the new domain just to /etc/krb5.so won't do the trick, as then it only checks the default domain, which is not "NEW.DOMAIN.NET". Any idea is welcome...

Regards, Thomas

Answer (score 1):

You can use FreeIPAs AD synchronization feature for this. It is not really the same but does the same job and is way easier to manage and control.